# Why ruby process starts getting: "getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution" on all remote calls before restart

Tags: ruby, dns

I have a couple of dedicated servers where I have background workers running for days sometimes before restart. When this happens (that they run for more than 24 hours it seems) then I start to get errors like this:

```
getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:540:in `open'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:540:in `tcp_socket'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:549:in `block in do_start'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:68:in `timeout'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:549:in `do_start'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:519:in `start'
```

The error will occur for ALL remote calls from that specific process, until it has been restarted (NOT hardware/server restart, just the ruby process). I have double-checked/confirmed that restarting the process works as a fix, since I have tried to SSH into the server, and run a new process along side the failing one, and this one would work flawlessly, while the faulty one still failed.

So my question is, why is this happening, and how can I resolve the issue in an other way than restarting the process every day?

I am on ruby 1.9.3 p194 and the background jobs are processed with the [sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/) gem (however I don't suspect that one to be responsible for the mess).

The servers are situated at http://www.hetzner.de (however I don't think they are to blame, since it's happening in-process)

**UPDATE**

Along side the above smtp call errors, I'm also getting errors like this, when doing simple http requests. This also resolves after a process restart:

```
# (Errno::EHOSTUNREACH) "No route to host - connect(2)"

/home/deployer/apps/au/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-http-persistent-2.8/lib/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:29:in `initialize'
/home/deployer/apps/au/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-http-persistent-2.8/lib/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:29:in `open'
/home/deployer/apps/au/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-http-persistent-2.8/lib/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:29:in `block in connect'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
/home/deployer/apps/au/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-http-persistent-2.8/lib/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:29:in `connect'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:750:in `start'
/home/deployer/apps/au/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-http-persistent-2.8/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:628:in `start'
/home/deployer/apps/au/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-http-persistent-2.8/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:888:in `reset'
/home/deployer/apps/au/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-http-persistent-2.8/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:567:in `connection_for'
/home/deployer/apps/au/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-http-persistent-2.8/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:926:in `request'
/home/deployer/apps/au/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.5.1/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:258:in `fetch'
/home/deployer/apps/au/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.5.1/lib/mechanize.rb:407:in `get'
```

Comment: post your code also here,only the error stack is not sufficient.

Comment: Well it's just a simple WhateverMailer.send_new_mail.deliver

Comment: Are you connecting over SSL?

Comment: In the above case yes, I'm requesting an url with Mechanize that's an https// address. I don't say that the two issues ARE the same, they just seem to occur simultaneously, and in both cases it has to resolve a host, so I was just thinking that they might be related.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186289/getaddrinfo-error-with-mechanize

Comment: related: http://serverfault.com/questions/266042/temporary-failure-in-name-resolution